# How to configure ZendX_JQuery in application.ini?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, zendx

I couldn't find any information about jQuery resource plugin. Is it possible to configure jQuery in application.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources.view[] =
pluginPaths.ZendX_Application_Resource_ = "ZendX/Application/Resource"
resources.jquery.localpath = "/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"
resources.jquery.stylesheet = "/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css"
resources.jquery.uilocalpath = "/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"
```

Comment: For some reason I get the error "Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception: Plugin by name 'JQuery' was not found in the registry". Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Ok, I found the problem - it's bug **ZF-9537**. It happens when you use **Jquery helper** in the **layout** file and **zend navigation**. More details are here [http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9537](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9537). I added _$this->bootstrap('view');_ before _$this->bootstrap('layout');_ in my Bootstrap and it works ok

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example iam using on "all" projects:

```
pluginPaths.ZendX_Application_Resource = "ZendX/Application/Resource"

; in production - load jquery from google cdn with jquery ui
resources.jquery.version    = 1.4.2
resources.jquery.ui_enable  = true
resources.jquery.ui_version = 1.8.7
resources.jquery.stylesheet = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/

; in development - load jquery local (not network in trains :-) )
resources.jquery.localpath    = "/js/library/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"
resources.jquery.ui_localpath = "/js/library/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.js"
resources.jquery.stylesheet   = "/public/css/jquery.ui/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css"
```

Comment: I don't usually use trains but it's a good idea! Sometimes internet in the office can be very slow when hundreds of people use the same proxy...

Comment: You might want to switch to the latest version 1.5 of jQuery - it has some nice new features and performance of some traversal methods  like .children(), .prev(), .next() has been improved [http://blog.jquery.com/2011/01/31/jquery-15-released/](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/01/31/jquery-15-released/)

Answer (score 0):

```
resources.jquery.version = 1
resources.jquery.ui_version = 1
```

load the newest version of jquery